# How to compress the number of class label by its frequency in multi-classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The project I have been working is a binary multi-label classification, which labels are more than 1000. Obviously, it is too much to get a good prediction. Say if I intend to select labels with 10% frequency, how am I supposed to achieve that.

The unprocessed label with missing values then I replace it with UNKNOWN, now it looks like this:

```
148          UNKNOWN
149    RM106 |RM159 
150          UNKNOWN
151           MI291 
152           TM187 
153          UNKNOWN
```

Here is my code to split and binarize the label class with scikit-learn.

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
y = [processed_val.split('|') for processed_val in processed]
y_encoded =mlb.fit_transform(y)
list(mlb.classes_)
```

Then I got labels like this:

```
 'MI053 ',
 'MI055 ',
 'MI056 ',
 'MI057 ',
 'MI059 ',
 'MI062 ',
```

This the matrix with 0s and 1s after multi-label binarization

```
y_encoded.shape
(134110L, 1039L)
```

I appreciate any method that can help to compress the number, not just strict to 10% frequency. I am both beginner in Python and machine learning. Anything you provided would be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With so many classes you could try building a one-versus-the-rest classifier

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html

Then you only need to worry about the predictions made on the classes you care about.  In your, case the most frequent classes.  You can use the sample_weight argument when you score your model to discount the impact on model performance.  Note, this will not change the fit of your model, just the scoring

When training you will want to set the stratify option (not None)

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

If results are poor, you may stick with the one-versus-the-rest approach, but just manually build a binary classifier for each class that you are interested in.  This will allow you to downsample the minority labels if you want to balance the dataset during training.

If you do not know the class of your sample, you should consider removing that data point rather than treat it as a separate class.  Perhaps test the performance of the model when 'unknown' is a class versus when those data are completely removed.

Comment: Can you be more specific about manually build a binary classifier? Also, the label class is imbalanced, most label is null (UNKNOWN). I did't expect the prediction of some labels rarely occur. So that's why I want to compress at the first place.

Comment: Sure.  Choose one of your labels, set it to '1' and set the rest to zeros.  You can now build a binary classifier using any method you choose.  You can balance the dataset by downsampling the majority.  The 'unknown' labels you should probably remove.  They will most likely confuse the classifier.